# Android : from list of events, how to find first event's start time has reached current time

Tags: android, timertask

In my app, I've list of events scheduled in next 5 days which are in ascedning order based on Start time.
Now I want to display next upcoming task in my app.
So my problem is if event's start time is matching current system time, then i want to remove that event from event list and next event should be on displayed in my activity as next upcoming event.

```
 E.g :
 Event1 2pm to 4pm.
 Event2 5pm to 6pm.
 Event3 8pm to 9pm.

 ArrayList<Event> allEvents;
 // Populate all Event data with event title and start time.
 Event = allEvents.get(0);
 Long top_event_start_time = Event.get_start_time();
```

Activity shows Event1 "Event1 scheduled at 2 pm".
At 2 pm I want activity to display Event2.

Please suggest which method would be appropriate.

Comment: I suppose you could start a separate background thread as a service which checks every [increment of time] for the smallest positive amount of time difference between the current and the next and display that? Assuming the events are sorted by time already and resorted every time an event is added.

Comment: Use  AlarmManager  https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html